# upload a pre-trained model on databricks mlflow experiment

Tags: machine-learning, databricks, mlflow, pre-trained-model

Is it possible to upload  a pre-trained machine learning model (from my local computer, for which I generated a model.pkl) on databricks, and serve it?
Or is it impossible on Databricks ?

Answer (score 1):

I managed it this way.

```
with mlflow.start_run(run_name="Your_MlFlow_RunName") as mlflow_run:
    model=load_model(<filepath_mod>)
    model.load_weights(<filepath_weights>)
    model.summary()
    mlflow.keras.log_model(model,"YourModelName",keras_module=tf.keras,registered_model_name="YourModelName")
```

But I did upload a zip file, not pickle  to also have access to best weights .

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile("/dbfs/FileStore/shared_uploads/<xxx@yyy>/TF_model/MyModel.zip", 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall("/dbfs/FileStore/shared_uploads/<xxx@yyy>/TF_model/")
```

Also note first time I did databraicks changed some filenames while unzipping, eg. MyModelWeights.data_0000 to MyModelWeights_data_0000 so had to write a fix for that too. Other times it did not happen though, so no idea why